Flex elements do not take all the available space before breaking into a new line
I'm trying to achieve the next design, where the elements take all the available space before breaking into a new line and also keeping the text centered:

Right now I'm using these styles in the container:
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;

but Im getting this result:

I'm using a simple container with divs inside, each div have a span and anchor element inside like this: 
there aren't any extra styles being applied

Please do not add code as a picture in your question. Always try to add the amount of code it would take someone to recreate your issue.

Make sure the  link has the next CSS property:
overflow-wrap: break-word;


You haven't shared your full HTML and CSS, so I can only answer your question by adding my own example. Note that it is easier for readers when you post code as text and do not use images.
The problem seems to be that you do not start at the start of the first line but center the content and that items cannot grow enough (do not take all available space due to the standard flex-grow behavior):
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Item 1</span><a href="#">Link</a></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Item 2</span><a href="#">Link</a></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Item 3</span><a href="#">Link</a></div>
  <!-- .... -->
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start; /* align items to the start of the line */
  gap: 10px; /* spacing between items */
}

.item {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* allows items to grow and take up any available space */
  text-align: center; /* centers text within each item */
}

/* Minimum space around the container (optional) */
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

To add a visual separator like a pipe (|) between your flex items, you can use the ::after pseudo-element in CSS. This approach allows you to insert content after each item except the last one, which is a common requirement for such separators.
.item::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px; /* specific spacing and styling needs */
  top: 50%; /* Aligns with the middle of the item */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* centered vertically */
  color: #ccc; /* Optional: sets the color of the separator */
}

.item:last-child::after {
  content: none; /* Removes the separator from the last item */
}

